# AWS RDS CLI describe-db-instances with available DBInstanceClass options

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am looking to extend the describe-db- a CLI command that, given a database engine and version, would show the available RDS database-instance-class options to create an RDS instance for that engine/version.

For instance, I need an RDS instance for MySQL version 5.7.19.  I need to know what my options are for the instance classes from the CLI.  I can run the following to output options and info on the engine and version, but I'm not sure what instance class options are permissible.

`aws rds describe-db-engine-versions --engine mysql --engine-version 5.7.19`

Comment: I'm not sure whether there exists a CLI approach, but you can find the information here in the doc. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html#Concepts.DBInstanceClass.Support